# How can I select rows newer than a week?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, intervals

Using MariaDB 10, I'd like to query `article` table for the past week articles:

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE category="News" AND created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

But it returns all articles instead.

> explain article ;

```
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(150)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| content     | mediumtext      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| created_at  | timestamp       | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| category    | varchar(64)     | NO   |     | test              |                |
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is backwards.  You want `>` not `<`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM article a
WHERE category = 'News' AND
      created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

For performance, you would want an index on `article(category, created_at)`.